# Comparing and matching product names from different stores/suppliers

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I’m trying to write a simple program to compare prices for products from different suppliers.
Different suppliers may call the same product different things.

For example, the following three strings refer to the same product:

- A2 Full Cream Milk Bottle 2l
- A2 Milk Full Cream 2L
- A2 Full Cream Milk 2L

Or the following two strings are the same product:

- Ambi Pur Air Freshener Car Voyage 8mL. Fresh Vanilla Flower fragrance. - 1 each
- Ambi Pur Air Freshener Voyage Primary 8ml

Furthermore - some products are not the same, but are similar (for example, Full Cream 2L Milk may encompass various similar products.)

The only bits of information I have on each product are the title, and a price.

What are currently recommended techniques for matching product strings like this?

From my Googling and reading other SO threads, I found:

- Some people recommend using Bayesian filtering techniques.
- Some recommend doing feature extraction on all the products strings. So you might extract things like brands (e.g. “A2”), Product (“Milk”) and capacity (“2L”) from the products, then create distance vectors between products, and use something like a binary classifier to match products (SVM was mentioned). However, I’m not sure of how to achieve this without a whole bunch of rules or regex? I’m assuming there’s probably smarter unsupervised learning methods of attacking this problem? Price could probably be another “feature” we could use to calculate the distance vector as well.
- Some people recommended using neural-network approaches, however, I wasn't able to find much in terms of concrete code or examples here.
- Others recommended using string similarity algorithms, such as Levenshtein distance, or the Jaro-Winkler distance.

Would you use one of the above techniques, or would you use a different technique?

Also, does anybody know of any example code, or even libraries for this sort of problem? I couldn't seem to find any.

(For example, I saw that some people were having performance problems with calculating the Jaro-Winkler distance for large data-sets. I was hoping there might be a distributed implementation of the algorithm (e.g. with Mahout), but wasn’t able to find anything concrete.)

Comment: How many different products (ball park estimation) will you have to manage?

Comment: It's a supermarket, so a fairly large number of items - I'd estimate in the tens of thousands?

Comment: Well all the suggestions are good, but supervised. And supervised learning on tens of thousands of classes is going to be hell... I can't think of any unsupervised approach though.

Comment: I had to implement similar case, what approach you have followed??

Comment: hey @victorhooi what approach did you end up using?

Comment: Haha , I'm excited that there's no SIMPLE way to go about this till today 2020

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would you use one of the above techniques, or would you use a different technique?

If I were doing this for real, I wouldn't use much machine learning. I'm sure most big companies have a database of brand and product names, and use that to match things up fairly easily. Some data sanitation might be needed - but its not much of an ML problem.

If you don't have that database, I'd say go simple. Convert everything to a feature-vector and do nearest neighbor search. Use that to create a tool to help you make a database. IE: you mark the first "A2 Whole Milk 2L" as "milk" yourself, and then see if its nearest neighbors are milk. Give yourself a way to quickly mark "yes" and "needs review", or some similar such option.

For simple data such as you suggested, where it will work 90% of the time - you should be able to get through the data with ease. I've done similar to label several thousand documents in a day.

Once you have your own database, resolving these should be pretty straightforward. You could reuse the code to create your database to handle "unseen" data.